# Display JSON object into DataGridView with JSON.NET

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I got `Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken` `onerow` which contain such JSON string:

```
{
  "n": 0,
  "i1": 0,
  "i2": 0,
  "t1": 0,
  "t2": 0,
  "d": 1,
  "c": [
    "202_Kamaz 4326-15",
    "0:00:00",
    "0:00:00",
    "",
    "0",
    "0 lt/100 km",
    "-----",
    "-----",
    ""
  ]  
}
```

How can I put all elements from `"c"` to different columns into DataGridView.

I need find a way to make `List` of rows with data taken from `"c"` and assign this `List` to my `DataGridView.DataSource`

Answer (score 0):

the below seems to do what you need.

Create a class to hold the deserialized json content.

```
public class Rootobject
{
    public int n { get; set; }
    public int i1 { get; set; }
    public int i2 { get; set; }
    public int t1 { get; set; }
    public int t2 { get; set; }
    public int d { get; set; }
    public string[] c { get; set; }
}
```

Then, get the payload. I've put it in an escaped string for this example.

```
var load = "{\r\n  \"n\": 0,\r\n  \"i1\": 0,\r\n  \"i2\": 0,\r\n  \"t1\": 0,\r\n  \"t2\": 0,\r\n  \"d\": 1,\r\n  \"c\": [\r\n    \"202_Kamaz 4326-15\",\r\n    \"0:00:00\",\r\n    \"0:00:00\",\r\n    \"\",\r\n    \"0\",\r\n    \"0 lt/100 km\",\r\n    \"-----\",\r\n    \"-----\",\r\n    \"\"\r\n  ]  \r\n}";
```

Now deserialize your json string.

```
 var json = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Rootobject>(load);
```

I've dropped a datagridview on my form called dgGridFromJson
Then loop through the array "c" and add each column accordingly.

```
 foreach (var item in json.c)
 {
     dgGridFromJson.Columns.Add(item, item);
 }
```

Hope that helps